# .net 7 BadRequestObjectResult uses CamelCase Policy

Tags: json, .net, validation, serialization, odata

I have configured the JsonSerializerOptions's PropertyNamingPolicy as null, OData all results gets as expected, but BadRequestObjectResult is still using camelcase policy.

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
     .AddJsonOptions(options => {
            
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null; // to don't change property names lowercase
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = null;
    })
```

```
protected ActionResult ValidationFailed()
    {
        var err = new ODataError 
        {
            Message = "Validation error",
            Details = ModelState.ToDictionary(
                kvp => kvp.Key, //.ToCamelCase(),
                kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
            ).Select(e => new ODataErrorDetail() {
                ErrorCode = e.Key,
                Message = string.Join("\n", e.Value.ToArray())
            }).ToList()
        };

       
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(err);
    }
```

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "Validation error",
        "details": [
            {
                "code": "person.corpid",
                "message": "Corpid field must be value"
            } 
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to get all results without changed like following.

```
{
    "Error": {
        "Code": "",
        "Message": "Validation error",
        "Details": [
            {
                "Code": "Person.Corpid",
                "Message": "Corpid field must be value"
            } 
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want this? The Validation error schema is defined [in RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807). If you want to display error details to users create an appropriate UI, don't try to modify the standard schema. The Problem Details data is meant for machine consumption, not display

Comment: On top of that, .NET already handles that specific schema through the [ProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails?view=aspnetcore-7.0) class. You don't even have to create your own DTOs to parse it. Other languages and frameworks implement this too

Comment: I need to same model error schema for all errors so I don't use ProblemDetails, but I tried following code but response json result is same. All property names are lowercase. 

`code
var problemDetails = new ValidationProblemDetails(ModelState);

            return new ObjectResult(problemDetails)
            {
                ContentTypes = { "application/problem+json" },
                StatusCode = 403,
            };
`

Comment: I already explained why that is - to ensure everyone has the same model error schema. That's not your schema to modify. It's a standard understood by everyone. It would be a very good idea to use it though, instead of creating yet another custom schema that clients would have to understand.

Comment: `so I don't use ProblemDetails` but you do, it's part of ASP.NET itself. If you use request validation, the errors are RFC7807. If request validation fails, your action won't even be called. The client will get a 400 with a ProblemDetails body

Comment: Well!, will all fieldnames serialize as original fieldnames because my main problem is that?